# Securing certain application with a second, longer password

Tags: password, root

In my day-to-day use of my computer, I need to supply my root password fairly often, since I frequently install something, or need to access certain system files.
Hence, to not constantly type in super long password, I've a fairly short one.

Yet, some very specific files in my home folder, as well as certain applications (e.g. cron) I would like to secure with a much longer password.

How can I achieve this?
(Is there some way that I can set up "two root users", one a short password and the other with a long one? Or is there another, non-root way in which I can secure those files and applications?
*You can get creative here ...* )

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Is there a longer answer too? I can't quite believe that there really is no workaround this issue.

Comment: A starting point: the sudoers file: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419330/can-i-restrict-a-user-with-root-privilegeswith-sudo-from-accessing-deleting-a

Comment: @vanadium I'm not sure if using the sudoers file this can be achieved: If root has a very long password, so that those few applications (e.g. cron) are proteced by a long password, then I think I will still make my life hard no matter how I edit the sudoers file. But there must be some other solution.